# parsley when errormessage or successmessage add class to a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley

I'm using Parsley in my form, so when an email address is being entered and this is a wrong syntax you will get an error message, when it is correct you will get a success message.

This all works fine, but i would like to add a class to a parent.
As you can see in the code below the input has a class called parsley-error.

When that class is in the input i want to add a class on the class block-1.

```
<div class="block-1 border-left">
<div class="radio item-1"></div>
<div class="form-group" data-popover-name="popover-paragraph-template">
    <div class="form-group" data-popover-name="popover-field-template">
        <div id="componentHider">
            <input type="email" data-parsley-email="" id="email" name="email" class="form-control parsley-error" placeholder="Nieuw e-mailadres" data-parsley-id="3622">
            <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-3622"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class handler `data-parsley-class-handler="#block-1"`

```
<div id="block-1" class="block-1 border-left">
<div class="radio item-1"></div>
<div class="form-group" data-popover-name="popover-paragraph-template">
    <div class="form-group" data-popover-name="popover-field-template">
        <div id="componentHider">
            <input type="email" data-parsley-class-handler="#block-1" data-parsley-email="" id="email" name="email" class="form-control parsley-error" placeholder="Nieuw e-mailadres" data-parsley-id="3622">
            <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-3622"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add a selector. in this example I used `id="block-1"`